# Customising Mesibo Chat bubbles

Tags: android, messaging, mesibo

We are using `Mesibo` for our live customer support. We have used their sample code from the `GitHub`.

So far it is working flawlessly for messaging and calls. We are able to customise colours, icons etc except their chat bubbles. Their chat bubbles needs some refinement so we want to replace them with our own for incoming and outgoing messages. However the documentation or sample code does not speak much about it.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is best to subclass `MesiboMessagingFragment` and use it instead of launching default user interface. That way you can customize virtually every aspect of mesibo UI.

1. Subclass `MesiboMessagingFragment`
2. implement `MesiboRecycleViewHolder.Listener` which is a wrapper around Android `RecycleView` functions.
3. Render and return your view in `Mesibo_onBindViewHolder()`

Hope it helps! If requires, I can get you a sample code.

Comment: I'm in a similar scenario but with `Invite Family and Friends section`. I cannot find a way to change the text that says `Hey, I use Mesibo for free messaging, voice and video calls`. Can you help me on this? Thx

Comment: You need to change in backend here https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-backend/blob/master/api_functions.php

Comment: @yumoji I noticed call don't go through when app is closed or destroyed. Is this the normal way? Also I couldn't find a way to change call fragment. I tried MesiboCallConfig c = new MesiboCallConfig();
 c.backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary); but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I have also tried to change the call fragment color but it didn't change. How to do it?